# Configuring Payara/GlassFish JMS connection factory for remote connection factory

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, payara, openmq

I am working on trying to understand how to properly configure Payara/GlassFish messaging so that messages are sent and received from a remote Open MQ server.

From the Payara/GlassFish admin console, I can go to Configurations > server-config > "Java Messaging Service" and from there I can setup a new "JMS Host" which points to the remote Open MQ server.  I then configure the "JMS Service Type" to REMOTE and do a few other things to get Payara/GlassFish to communicate with the Open MQ borker instance on the remote host.  I understand this.

Now when setting up a connection factory, I go to Resources > "JMS Resources" > "Connection Factories"  When setting up the connection factory, what I don't understand is the need for the "AddressList" property if using a remote JMS broker.  If I do the 1st step and update the "Java Messaging Service" to REMOTE and to connect to a remote broker, is the "AddressList" property still needed?  If I do need "AddressList", then what's the point of the "Java Messaging Service" configuration?